# ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer un bucle del alfabeto sin necesidad de seleccionar un elemento de una lista?

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber si es posible evitar definir la lista e ingresar los elementos que deseo, en este caso condicionales que se basan en comparaciones con los índices (numéricos). ¿Existe algún método o función que puede ahorrarme todo este trabajo "sucio" únicamente para el alfabeto?

```
list=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

for i in list:
    print(i)
```

Agradezco su apoyo. Excelente día!

Comment: No está muy claro para qué lo necesitas, pero el módulo `string` tiene una variable llamada `ascii_lowercase` que son las letras del alfabeto en minúsculas. Puedes usarlas en un bucle, como en `for letra in string.ascii_lowercase:`

Comment: El problema con las respuestas de @Pablochaches y CandidMoe es que fallan en obtener la ñ.

Comment: Lo mismo con la idea de @abulafia

Comment: @DanteS. `letras=string.ascii_lowercase[:14]+'ñ'+string.ascii_lowercase[14:]` :-)

Comment: Ahi si funca con ñ :)

Comment: Recomiendo usar la idea de Abulafia ;)

Comment: @DanteS. Buen punto, ni se me paso por la cabeza

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: @abulafia, intenté hacer un salto de línea al imprimirlo, pero no he podido conseguir que se imprima de forma vertical, cómo se puede imprimir verticalmente?

Comment: `for c in letras: print(c)` Te refieres a algo como esto?

Comment: @abulafia exacto, muchas gracias. Todos los días estoy aprendiendo algo nuevo de programación!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ord()` te da el valor numerico de un caracter
- `chr()` lo regresa a caracter.

Empiezas el loop con `ord('a')` y terminas con `ord('z')`, dentro del loop lo conviertes en caracter y listo

```
begin = ord('a')
end = ord('z') + 1
i = begin
while i != end:
    caracter = chr(i)
    # Lo que quieras hacer
    i += 1
```

Comment: En lugar de un while, podrías también hacer `for i in range(begin, end)`

Answer (score 2):

Hay 26 letras desde la 'a' hasta la 'z'.

`ord('a')` nos da el ASCII de la letra 'a'. A eso le sumamos 1, 2, 3, ... y obtenemos el ASCII de 'b', 'c', 'd'.

Con `chr`, convertimos el ASCII a caracter para imprimir:

```
for i in range(26):
    print(chr(ord('a') + i))
```